# Adding default filter on many2one tree view - OpenErp Custom module

Tags: xml, odoo

I have added this line in XML:

```
<field name="context">{"search_default_current_year": 1}</field>
```

But this works only for it's own view. What i want is to set it default even in many2one view. Is there a way?

Edited code:
Search View:

```
<record id="urdhershpenzim_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">urdhershpenzim.select</field>
        <field name="model">urdher.shpenzim</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Kerko Urdhershpenzimi">
                   <group>
                    <filter name="draft" icon="terp-document-new" string="Draft" domain="[('state','=','draft')]"/>
                    <filter name="confirmed" icon="terp-check" string="Konfirmuar" domain="[('state','=','confirmed')]"/>
                    <filter name="cancel" icon="gtk-cancel" string="Anulluar" domain="[('state','=','cancel')]"/>
                       <separator orientation="vertical"/>
                       <filter name="current_year" icon="terp-gtk-media-pause" string="Current Year" domain="['|',('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-01-01')),('date','=',False)]" help="Current year"/> <!--commprog-orjada-->
                       <separator orientation="vertical"/>
                   <field name="name"/>
                       <field name="institucion_id"/>
                       <field name="furnitor_id"/>
                       <field name="tipi"/>
                       <field name="date"/>
                </group>
                   <newline/>
                   <group expand="0" string="Group By..." groups="base.group_extended">
                    <filter string="State" icon="terp-stock_effects-object-colorize" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'state'}"/>
                </group>
           </search>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Action:

```
<record id="action_urdhershpenzimi" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Urdhershpenzimi</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">urdher.shpenzim</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_model">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('institucion_lloji','=',True)]</field>
        <field name="context">{"search_default_current_year":1}</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="urdhershpenzim_filter"/>
    </record>
```

Comment: Edit the question and elaborate, there is no `Many2one` view in `odoo`

Comment: More information would be really helpful. Your code seems to be a part of a window action, which won't be used on many2one fields in form views. If you want to change the behaviour of many2one searches in form views, you have to change the context of the field definition of that form view.

Comment: I think the filter named `current_year` belongs to another model, and that why this filter not working as you expected

Comment: So post your search view for the two models(The one where work and the other)

Comment: @arryph that is what im looking for. When i click the Search More button on m2o, the filter does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your question is:

> How can I force "some field" to **always have the same domain**?

**The answer is that you can set the `domain` value on the field definition (in Python).**

---

As you said, the below `context` works, but only to restrict the field's options on one specific view.

```
<field name="context">{"search_default_current_year": 1}</field>
```

From the search view you posted, we can determine that the filter applies the below domain to the field. The domain basically says "only allow selecting any records whose `date` value is **on or after January 1st of this year** or **has no date selected**.

```
<filter name="current_year"
        domain="['|',('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-01-01')),('date','=',False)]"/>
```

As I mentioned, the same domain can be applied *on the field's Python definition* and that field will have the domain applied everywhere.

```
from datetime import datetime
from odoo import fields, models


SomeClass(models.Model):
    _name = 'some.class'
    _description = 'Some Class that has "urdher.shpenzim" as a Many2one field'

    urdher_shpenzim_id = fields.Many2one(
        'urdher.shpenzim`,
        domain=['|', ('date', '=', False),
                ('date', '>=', '{}-01-01'.format(datetime.now().year))])
```

You might have to make some changes to the format command for the date, but the idea is the same.

Be sure to check the Odoo Documentation on [Fields](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#fields) and [Domains](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#domains) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe i was a bit unclear to explain my problem. But what seemed to fix it was a line in action window referring to the tree view.

Comment: <field name="view_id" ref="urdhershpenzim_tree"/>

Comment: @Arges You can post your own answer of the solution. Try to include more details if you can so that it might help someone with a similar problem in the future.